# When can a polynomial be written as a polynomial function of another polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given two polynomials $p(x)$ and $g(x)$, how do I ascertain whether or not $p(x)$ is expressible as

$$p(x)= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i (g(x))^i,$$

where $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are constant coefficients.

**Example:** Let $p(x)= x^6-3x^4+4x^2-1$ and $g(x)= x^2-1$, then $$p(x)= (g(x))^3+g(x)+1.$$

Comment: You can be sure $p(x)$ is *not* a polynomial in $g(x)$ if $\deg p$ is not divisible by  $\deg g$.

Comment: For general polynomial decomposition algorithms $\ p(x) = f(g(x))\,$ see my comment [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/658451/242)

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure how to put it in a simple condition, but there's a procedure that allows to check whether $p(x)=w(g(x))$ for $w$ being a polynomial function.

Let's perform a repeated polynomial division of $p$ over $g$, that is let $q_n(x)$ and $r_n(x)$, $n\in\mathbb N$ be polynomials such that $\deg r_n < \deg g$, $q_n \neq 0$ and
$$ p(x) = q_0(x) g(x) + r_0(x) \\ q_0(x) = q_1(x) g(x) + r_1(x) \\ q_1(x) = q_2(x) g(x) + r_2(x) \\ q_2(x) = q_3(x) g(x) + r_3(x) \\ \dots $$
Such division will always end in a finite number of steps. If all $r_n$ are constants, that is $\deg r_n = 0$, $r_n(x) = r_n$, then $$ p(x) = \sum_n r_{n} \big(g(x)\big)^n $$
If at any point we get $r_n(x)$ that is not constant, then $p(x)$ cannot be expressed as a polynomial of $g(x)$.

Comment: Is there a reference?

Comment: @Paracosmiste This is known as the $g$-adic expansion of $\,p\,$ in the general case when the coefficients $r_i$  have degree $< \deg g.\,$ It is easily seen to be unique.. It is analogous to radix expansions of integers and generalizes Taylor series expansions. If is often used to compute partial fraction expansions.