# When is a polynomial a composition of a polynomial with some (unspecified) non-linear polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

[When can a polynomial be written as a polynomial function of another polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296843/when-can-a-polynomial-be-written-as-a-polynomial-function-of-another-polynomial) asks whether, given $p$ and $q$ polynomials, there is a polynomial $w$ with $$
p(x) = w(q(x))
$$
which is a good question with a nice answer. We can try to generalize to ask:

Given a polynomial $p$, do there exist polynomials $q$ and $w$ with 
$$
p(x) = w(q(x)).
$$

That is to say, we can ask the question not for a *specific* $q$, but ask whether *any* such $q$ exists.

Alas, that question isn't interesting, for $q(x) = x$ and $w = p$ provides a solution for any $p$; indeed, we can let $q$ be any linear polynomial $q(x) = ax + b$ with $a \ne 0$ and then find $w$ (assuming we're working over a field, which is the case I'm thinking of), essentially by substitution. So my question is this:

> Given a polynomial $p$ over a field, is there a (relatively easy) way to determine whether there's a non-linear polynomial $q$ and some polynomial $w$ with the property that $$p(x) = w(q(x))?$$

I'd be happy with an answer even over some specific field like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Since $\deg p = \deg w\cdot \deg q$ it it is necessary that $\deg p$ is not prime. This is far from sufficient. (And this assumes both $q$ and $w$ are non-linear.)

Comment: Is this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/672847/42969 the answer to your question?

Comment: It would be interesting to learn what is known about solving such problems with integer coefficients.

Comment: There are efficient polynomial decomposition algorithms due to Ritt, Barton and Zippel, Kozen and Landau, etc, e.g. see [here.](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/Papers/poly.pdf). These are used in computer algebra systems.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: the final question explicitly requires $q$ non-linear.

Comment: @MartinR: thanks -- that's *exactly* what I was looking for. If you'd like to turn that pointer into an answer, I'll accept it; if not, I'll do so via a community-wiki answer, so that the question gets  closed out.

Comment: When $p(x)=w(q(x))$ has $p'(x)=w'(q(x))q'(x),$ When $p,w,q\in\mathbb Q[x]$, then if $p'(x)$ is irreducible then $p(x)$ can't be written in this form.

Answer (score 1):

@MartinR points out that math.stackexchange.com/a/672847/42969 answers my question quite well (with a solution developed by someone who was a high-school student at the time!)

@BillDubuque points out that computer algebra systems have algorithms to do this kind of thing as well, like [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/Papers/poly.pdf).